# two arguments of arry and read the columns

Tags: c

i have simple tab:

```
int rows = atoi(argv[1]);
int tab[rows][2];
```

and i'm forwarding it to func by:

```
myFunc(tab);
void myFunc(int (*tab)[2]);
```

how can I read the number of rows?
I still to try about:

```
int readRowInMyFunc = sizeof(tab)/(sizeof(int **));
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: the type of an array is simply a pointer.  You can't declare a function (myFunc) with an argument being an array of a particular size.  Pass the pointer to the head of the array into myFunc as well as the number of rows in the array (2 arguments) `void myFunc(int *tab, int rows)`

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(tab) = rows * 2 * sizeof(int)
```

so

```
rows = sizeof(tab) / (2*sizeof(int))
```

*Note this is a really bad idea to create your array on the stack with a dynamic size. What if I run your program with argv[1] = 100000000000000000000?*